# Equation paramétrique du second degré

Tags: elementary-number-theory

C'est un exercice du concours d'admission en économie de L'Université Protestante au Congo.
Voici la question: déterminer la valeur de m pour que la fonction f(x)=(x-7)/(mx²+ mx+m+1) admette deux asymptotes verticales.

---

[Edited English translation]:

> This is an exercise from the economics entrance examination of L'Université Protestante au Congo. The question is: determine the value of $m$ such that the function:
>   $$
> f(x) = \frac{x - 7}{mx^2 + mx + m + 1}
> $$
>   has two vertical asymptotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order that function $$f(x) = \frac{x - 7}{mx^2 + mx + m + 1}$$ shows two vertical asymptotes, the denominator must cancel twice. This first implies that $m \neq 0$ (otherwise, the quadratic would not be anymore a quadratic).

Now, the roots of $${mx^2 + mx + m + 1}=0$$ are given by $$x_{\pm}=-\frac{m \pm \sqrt{-3 m^2-4 m}}{2 m}$$ and so the requirement is $$3m^2+4m=m(3m+4)\lt 0$$ which then implies $$-\frac{4}{3} <m<0$$

Comment: Thank you @claude-leibovici your resolution seems logical. But only by replacing m by  -4 / 3, f (x) has no solution in IR, was I wrong or not?

Comment: This answer is incorrect. There is only one vertical asymptote when $m=-1/57$ because the $x-7$ cancels.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: If $m \neq 0$, then $mx^2 +mx+m+1 = m(x^2 + x + 1 + 1/m)$. Using the quadratic equation, the roots of $x^2+x+1+1/m$ are $$ -\frac{1}{2}\pm \frac{\sqrt{1-4(1+1/m)}}{2}.$$ You will get two real roots whenever the discriminant $1-4(1+1/m)$ is positive. That is, when $1-4(1+1/m) > 0$.

Can you take it from there?

Comment: I'm looking for the value of "m".

Comment: <b> Indice</b>: Si $m \neq 0$, alors $mx^2 +mx+m+1 = m(x^2 + x + 1 + 1/m)$. En utilisant la formule quadratique, les racines de $x^2+x+1+1/m$ sont $$ -\frac{1}{2}\pm \frac{\sqrt{1-4(1+1/m)}}{2}.$$ Vous aurez deux racines réelles à chaque fois que le discriminant $1-4(1+1/m)$ est positif. C'est-à-dire lorsque $1-4(1+1/m) > 0$. 

Pouvez-vous poursuivre à partir de là?

Comment: Oui biensûr! Mais celle-ci est une équation paramétrique du second degré, il faut d'abord trouver la valeur du paramètre (m) laquelle va nous aider à résoudre rationnellement l'équation. Merci!

Comment: ∆(m)=m²-4(m)(m+1)=m²-4m²-4m=-3m²-4m.
∆(m)=0 alors -3m²-4m=0
m= ?

Comment: Ce que Tom a fait, c'est diviser d'abord l'équation par $m$. Cela revient au même, en autant que $m \ne 0$. Mis à part certains cas exceptionnels que vous aurez peut-être à exclure, vous cherchez $m$ de façon que l'équation ait deux racines. Cela correspond au fait que le discriminant soit *positif*, et non pas nul comme vous l'affirmez.

Comment: Je peux en déduire que ce cas est une particularité? Déterminer la valeur de m pour que la fonction f(x)=(x-7)/(mx²+ mx+m+1) admette deux asymptotes verticales.

Comment: Écoutez, je vais donner des exemples qui ne correspondent pas au problème pour dire ce qui se passe. La fonction $g(x) = (x-7)/(x^2 - 9)$, elle a combien d'asymptotes verticales? La fonction $h(x) = (x-7)/(x^2 + 2x + 1)$? Et $k(x) = (x-7)/(x^2 + 9)$?

Comment: In order other participants can follow, may I suggest we all write in English ? (I am French)

Comment: Claude, I thought it would be more useful for the OP, has he posted his original question in French and appeared to have some difficulty following Tom's answer.